# google map SVG markers - move, closepath & background fills

Tags: arrays, google-maps, svg

I have got basics of SVG google markers but I have to make several redundant points to get effect that I want. In example below I am trying to make a "house" with floating S in the middle.   I want to reduce points in array without loosing fill background. I think I need to use Using M (moveto) or z (closepath) but these cause me to loose background colour

Also can anyone recommend a tool to help draw points onXY axis suitable for SVG. I am using Excel, which a not a great draw program.

```
<style> 
    #map-canvas {        
        height: 350px;
        width: 600px;        
    }
</style>    

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>           
<script src="../jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">


    var map;
    var polyLine;
    var polyOptions;
    var iconSize = 2;

    function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

            addPoint(event);
        });
    }

    function addPoint(event) {

        var pathHouse = 'M  0,1 , 0,-1 , -7,-1 , -7,-16 , -10,-16 , 0,-26 , 10,-16 , 7,-16 , 7,-1  , 0,-1 , 0,-4 , -3,-4 , -4,-5 ,-3,-4 ,  3,-4 , 4,-5 , 4,-9 , 3,-10 ,  -3,-10 , -4,-11 , -4,-15 , -3,-16 ,  3,-16 , 4,-15 , 4,-15 , 3,-16 ,  -3,-16 , -4,-15 , -4,-11 , -3,-10 ,  3,-10 , 4,-9 , 4,-5 , 3,-4 , -3,-4 , -4,-5 , -3,-4 , 0,-4 , z';     

        var icon = {

            path: pathHouse ,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: .6,
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            strokeWeight: 0,
            scale: iconSize,
            strokeColor: 'black',
            strokeWeight: 1 
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map,
            draggable: false,
            icon: icon,
            zIndex : -20
        });

        map.panTo(event.latLng);

        iconSize += .05;
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();
});

</script>

<p>Click to add markers</p>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an S-shaped hole in your filled house, you need to have the path consist of two sub-paths.  Each subpath starts with a Move (M) and describes the **outline** of the shape.

So the first subpath describes the outline of the house. And the second subpath describes the outline of the "S".

You have the house part ok, but your "S" is just the skeleton of an "S".

> Also can anyone recommend a tool to help draw points onXY axis suitable for SVG. I am using Excel, which a not a great draw program.

Yikes!  Any modern verctor editor can produce SVG files.  Try the (free) Inkscape program.

Comment: Thanks for push! Google map markers seems to only accept a small subset of SVG vocabulary.  Inkscape and others generate code that cannot be used as makers in google maps.  I will take another look.

Answer (score 0):

revised coordinates:

```
var pathHouse = 'M  0,1 , 0,-1 , -7,-1 , -7,-16 , -10,-16 ,  0,-26 , 10,-16 ,   7,-16 ,     7,-1 ,  0,-1 , M -1,-4 , 1,-4 , 1,-16 , 5,-16 , 5,-17 , -5,-17 , -5,-16 , -1,-16 , -1,-4 ,  0,-4 , 0,-17 , z';
```